# as I take the points2f from a vector

Tags: visual-c++, vector

I have a vector of points and I want to analyze each point (coordinates) of a matrix. How can I write the vector is so:

```
{
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> Q1;
    {
        ...
        /*so loading points with a for of another Mat*/
        Q1.push_back(cv::Point2f(i, j));
    }
    for (i = 0; i < Q1.size; i++)
    {
        /*here as recovery every single coordinate ?*/
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what the question is.

Comment: I solved. I tired this ... int x = Q1[i].x;